# Find propositional formulas $\phi$ and $\psi$ such that $(\phi \rightarrow (\psi \rightarrow (¬\psi)))$ is a theorem of L.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, formal-proofs

Find propositional formulas $\phi$ and $\psi$ such that $(\phi \rightarrow (\psi \rightarrow (¬\psi)))$ is a theorem of L.

So every axiom is a theorem of L so I thought there would be some way to write $(\phi \rightarrow (\psi \rightarrow (¬\psi)))$ in terms of some variables $p_1, p_\ldots$ so that it is one of the axioms;

(A1) $(\phi \rightarrow ( \psi \rightarrow \phi))$

(A2) $((\phi \rightarrow (\psi \rightarrow \chi))\rightarrow((\phi \rightarrow \psi)\rightarrow(\psi \rightarrow \chi)))$

(A3) $(((¬\phi) \rightarrow (¬\psi)) \rightarrow (\psi \rightarrow \phi))$

But I am not sure how to do that or if it is even the correct approach.
Thanks

**By trying to use A3 I have got $((p_1 \rightarrow (p_2 \rightarrow p_3)) \rightarrow ((p_1 \rightarrow p_2) \rightarrow (p_1 \rightarrow p_3)))$ but I expect that is totally wrong.**

Comment: If it is a theorem of $L$ then it must be always true, just make a truth table and see, which conditions $\phi$ must satisfy.

Comment: @GitGud I am not sure whether you created [tag:formal-proofs] tag, but this is the oldest question I found which has this tag. If you created this tag, could you have a look at a post about this tag [on meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/17016/whats-the-formal-proofs-tag-for)? Thanks!

Comment: @MartinSleziak I did create it. Thanks, I'll have a look.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the first axiom, it's enough to require that $\phi=\left(\neg \psi\right)$, so let $\phi=(\neg p)$ and $\psi =p$.

Comment: can you just say that? because initially thats what I thought but then I didn't think you could do that. so would the answer be;
$(p_1 \rightarrow ((¬p_1) \rightarrow p_1))$ ? Or am I understanding it wrong?

Comment: The axioms are closed under uniform substitution, so that wouldn't work. Would it?

Comment: @HunanRostomyan I don't know what you're talking about, I've never heard of uniform substitution.

Comment: @GitGud It means $(p \rightarrow (q \rightarrow p))$ is an instance of (A1), while $(p \rightarrow (q \rightarrow r))$ is not. In other words, you can't replace single ocurrences of variables, but have to substitute them all.

Comment: @HunanRostomyan thanks, could you possibly help towards answering the question??

Comment: @ZZS14 Your example doesn't work as the first axiom gives you what you say, but you want $(p_1 \rightarrow ((¬p_1) \rightarrow (\neg(\neg p_1))))$. Try $(\neg p)\to (p\to (\neg p))$ instead.

Comment: how did you get to that?

Comment: @ZZS14 What exactly?

Comment: @HunanRostomyan Sorry for the delay, you're right, but how am I not doing what you described?

Comment: I've confused myself. so I want to use Axiom 1? and substitute $\phi$ for $(¬\psi)$?

Comment: @GitGud Doesn't what you described get us: $\lnot\psi \rightarrow (\psi \rightarrow \lnot\psi)$ instead of $\phi \rightarrow (\psi \rightarrow \lnot\psi)$?

Comment: @HunanRostomyan You are correct, I just don't see how it contradicts anything of what I've said. We want to find formulas $\phi$ and $\psi$ such that $(\phi \rightarrow (\psi \rightarrow (¬\psi)))$ holds. Axiom 1 with $\phi=\neg p$ and $\psi = p$ yields $(\underbrace{(\neg p)}_{\phi}\to (\underbrace{p}_{\psi}\to \underbrace{(\neg p)}_{\phi =\neg \psi}))$.

Comment: @GitGud Substituting not psi in the formula given yields an axiom! That's right. I incorrectly interpreted you as saying that: Axiom 1, when not not is substituted for phi, yields the given formula. You're absolutely right.

Comment: @ZZS14 See my comment above. Does it help?

Comment: yes but i am now confused because you have $((¬p) \rightarrow (p \rightarrow (¬p)))$

Comment: and the question is $(\phi \rightarrow (\psi \rightarrow (¬\psi)))$ so surely we should have $(p \rightarrow (p \rightarrow (¬p)))$

Comment: @ZZS14 I don't understand why you think it should be that way. Are you thinking $\phi$ can't start with $\neg$?

Comment: yeah because in the question we are given it doesn't have a negation?

Comment: @ZZS14 It can, $\phi$ is a formula. You should know from before you encountered this problem that $(\neg p)$ is a formula, where $p$ is a propositional letter. So you can rightfully replace $\phi$ with $(\neg p)$.

Comment: okay i was just expecting something of the form that was given in the question. thank you. just to clarify my answer now is ((¬p) $\rightarrow$(p $\rightarrow$ (¬p))) and i can check this by constructing the truth table and it has to have truth value T in all rows since it is a theorem of L which must be a tautology?

Comment: @ZZS14 Yes, and the completeness theorem tells you that since it is a tautology, it is provable. Another way to confirm it to think about it semantically. If it was false, then $(\neg p)$ would be true and $((p → (¬p)))$ would be false. But $(\neg p)$ being true means $p$ is false, so $(p → (¬p))$ must be true. So $(p → (¬p))$ is both true and false, a contradiction.

Comment: thank you for all your help

Comment: @ZZS14 You're welcome.

Comment: ((¬p) →(p → (¬p))) is a substitution instance of (ϕ→(ψ→ϕ)) (or one can obtain ((¬p) →(p → (¬p))) from (ϕ→(ψ→ϕ)) by substitution).  Since (uniform) substitution consists of a truth-preserving transformation, and (ϕ→(ψ→ϕ)) is an axiom it follows by the soundness meta-theorem that ((¬p) →(p → (¬p))) is a tautology.

Comment: This answer seems elegant, but it *might* miss the intended lesson of this problem.

Answer (score 4):

Axioms are frmulated with *schematic letters*. In :

> **(A1)** $(A→(B→A))$

$A$ and $B$ are variable in the *metalanguage* which stay for formulae; we may replace them with formulae whatever and we will get always an instance of the axiom.

Thus, if $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are formulae, as suggested by Git Gud, the following are both instances of **(A1)** :

> $\vdash (\varphi → (\psi → \varphi))$

and

> $\vdash (\lnot \psi →(\psi → \lnot \psi))$.

The first one has been obtained with the subst of the formula $\varphi$ in place of the *schematic letter* $A$ and with $\psi$ in place of $B$.

The second one with the subst of the formula $\lnot \psi$ in place of the *schematic letter* $A$ and with $\psi$ in place of $B$.

The only care we must take is that substitution must be *uniform* (as per comment of Hunan Rostomyan) i.e. we must replace each occurences of, let say, $A$ with the *same* formula.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question and I think there are three options:

- $ \phi \equiv  (\psi \rightarrow (¬\psi) $ (for example if $ \phi $ is $  \psi \rightarrow  \lnot \psi)$  but simple equality is enough.
- $ \lnot \phi $ is a theorem , then you get **impossible antecedent**.
- $ \psi \rightarrow \lnot\psi $ is a theorem, what will be the case if  $\lnot\psi $ is a theorem , then you get **true concequent**.

Each of these three off course stands for an infinite number of formulas so have a pick.

Answer (score 0):

What is "(ϕ→(ψ→(¬ψ)))"?  It is a conditional.

What do we know about all conditionals?  They have an antecedent and a consequent.

What is the antecedent of (ϕ→(ψ→(¬ψ))), and what is it's consequent?  The antecedent is ϕ and the consequent is (ψ→(¬ψ).

So, how might we make (ϕ→(ψ→(¬ψ))) into a theorem?  Well, all tautologies are theorems by the completeness theorem.  So, how might we make (ϕ→(ψ→(¬ψ))) into a tautology?

Well, let's suppose we substituted ϕ with (ψ→(¬ψ)).  We would then have the well-formed formula [(ψ→(¬ψ))→(ψ→(¬ψ))].  Thus we might substitute  ϕ with (p→(¬p)) and ψ with p to obtain a formula which is a theorem of L.